# This class is not key value coding-compilant for the key optionsSection

Tags: ios, ios6, sdk, tabbar

I am a newcomer in developing. I make my project with TabBar. When I run my project on iPhone Simulator I can see FirstViewController. When I put on my Second Controller Icon on TabBar, project crashes and give me that issue.

> 2013-07-05 12:31:16.238 MyProject[26912:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key optionsSection.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1d76012 0x1529e7e 0x1dfefb1 0xcc5e41 0xc475f8 0xc470e7 0xc71b58 0x37b019 0x153d663 0x1d7145a 0x379b1c 0x23e7e7 0x23edc8 0x38d28e 0x23eff8 0x23f232 0x2608c9 0x260704 0x25ebda 0x25ea5c 0x260647 0x153d705 0x1612c0 0x161258 0x383ff4 0x153d705 0x1612c0 0x161258 0x222021 0x22257f 0x222056 0x387af9 0x153d705 0x1612c0 0x161258 0x222021 0x22257f 0x2216e8 0x190cef 0x190f02 0x16ed4a 0x160698 0x1896df9 0x1896ad0 0x1cebbf5 0x1ceb962 0x1d1cbb6 0x1d1bf44 0x1d1be1b 0x18957e3 0x1895668 0x15dffc 0x292d 0x2855)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

Please, give me some solutions of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have provided a key in interface builder to some `UILabel` or any such UI instance of that missing key and then removed,that causes that error. Ctrl click the file's owner of view controller and remove the missing key(key with a yellow cross mark) from there.

Its the one of the answers I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475750/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-error/17476144?noredirect=1#comment25396935_17476144) on this SO thread whose problem looks just like yours.

Comment: If it solves your problem, you should accept it as the answer to help the future visitors.